# .Net Core Pod Restarts for a containerized Application running on Kubernetes in AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-eks, asp.net-core-7.0

We are using .Net Core 7 image (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0) deployed to Amazon EKS. We are seeing pod restarts and are unable to track down what is causing the restarts.
We see the below in Pod logs that the application is shutting down.
2023-08-21T02:59:34-04:00 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-08-21T11:59:47-04:00 Application is shutting down...

1. Tried logging unhandled exceptions using an unhandled exception service for the entire app and nothing is being logged there.
2. Deployed an app and even with no traffic to the site we are seeing restarts.
3. Added an entry in *startup.cs* to ignore unhandled exceptions in background services

```
services.Configure<HostOptions>(hostOptions => { 
    hostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior =  BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore;
});
```

Any other pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the sounds of it, I'd guess that the container is being shut down by the orchestrator.

Comment: can you describe the pod? What is pod's Error code?

Comment: Yeah, its Exit code 0. 
terminated
Reason:Reason: Completed - exit code: 0
Started at: 2023-08-22T01:52:14-04:00
Finished at: 2023-08-22T06:55:34-04:00

Comment: You could try using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/determine-reason-pod-failure/ though I'm not sure it works on Windows.